# How can I plot two geom_tile next to each-other so they align as in a Heatmap, using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I would like to plot a Heatmap including coloured annotation bars. A bit of background to the data.

I have simplified the example data below.

I have patient id's, and a numerical measurement (value_mean) that I would like to plot per patient per "emm_type" in the form of a Heatmap. Each "emm_type" falls into a "cluster" and a "pattern". So I would like the Heatmap to include a coloured panel delineating these variables aligned with their respective emm_type.

Here is s sample of my data

```
> dput(example)
structure(list(id = c("RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", 
"RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", 
"RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0475", 
"RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0504", 
"RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0475", 
"RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", 
"RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0475", 
"RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0504", 
"RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0504", 
"RF0504", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", 
"RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504", "RF0475", "RF0504"
), cluster = c("a-c2", "a-c2", "a-c3", "a-c3", "a-c4", "a-c4", 
"a-c5", "a-c5", "d1", "d1", "d2", "d2", "d2", "d2", "d3", "d3", 
"d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", "d4", 
"d4", "e1", "e1", "e2", "e2", "e2", "e2", "e3", "e3", "e3", "e3", 
"e3", "e3", "e3", "e3", "e3", "e3", "e4", "e4", "e4", "e4", "e4", 
"e4", "e4", "e4", "e4", "e4", "e6", "e6", "e6", "e6", "e6", "e6", 
"e6", "e6", "m19", "m19", "m218", "m218", "m233", "m233", "m6", 
"m6", "m74", "m74", "m95", "m95"), pattern = c("a-c", "a-c", 
"a-c", "a-c", "a-c", "a-c", "a-c", "a-c", "d", "d/a-c", "d", 
"e", "d", "e", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
"d", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
"e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", 
"e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "d", "e", "d", "e", "d", "e", "d", "a-c", 
"a-c", "d/a-c", "d/a-c", "a-c", "a-c", "a-c", "a-c", "d", "d", 
"d", "d"), value_mean = c(1.82898259773807, 2.74970378862732, 
2.31836858483114, 1.76297558336274, 6.99379366342489, 2.15775104765085, 
9.81401417902465, 5.94493622813449, 6.42938334280903, 4.93258400244736, 
4.42293379133012, 35.7119300124525, 85.8843942732351, 6.11004188703959, 
4.46626647704635, 5.06748534630747, 2.34493589810343, 3.67864160152857, 
3.49413303648271, 4.54325723822265, 11.6241914407818, 6.52797483395025, 
2.29277958694861, 7.80004526681732, 2.69910122940354, 3.51802243804242, 
6.70909678383865, 4.99681912787639, 5.54367727879201, 9.26383310897086, 
4.57249586682161, 4.47787503848692, 12.3177425173967, 15.4240417229311, 
4.14187570530094, 32.2447795214283, 2.8171424279428, 3.62644580807153, 
79.8173447817745, 2.86868514917333, 4.13675844930625, 2.89891922608397, 
120, 5.07500759868863, 3.31961544500323, 9.76557528920087, 4.93060063573198, 
4.65192299498109, 66.3579869162384, 2.22596680234449, 5.70995502095345, 
4.26850758713846, 120, 25.6383266263976, 2.90543208425715, 8.40935809851042, 
2.31807635931822, 8.49055234623605, 3.29831448162297, 3.65068984963035, 
1.93567603146573, 2.49808722814557, 3.14095440681389, 2.08508075133288, 
3.08360524948663, 1.74613534854807, 1.91624362373354, 3.797786602908, 
3.06755845905157, 3.11530841942899, 2.06455239407449, 1.71396244231883, 
5.7985222607316, 3.74822367820585), group = c("case", "control", 
"case", "control", "case", "control", "case", "control", "case", 
"control", "case", "case", "control", "control", "case", "control", 
"case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "case", "control", 
"case", "case", "control", "control", "case", "case", "case", 
"case", "case", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"case", "case", "case", "case", "case", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "case", "case", "case", "case", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "case", "control", 
"case", "control", "case", "control", "case", "control", "case", 
"control", "case", "control"), emm_type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 
25L, 27L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 37L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 
37L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 38L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 47L, 49L, 
51L, 53L, 47L, 49L, 51L, 53L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 57L, 
57L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L), .Label = c("197", "1", "238.1", "12", 
"39.4", "3.1", "36.2", "54.1", "71", "100", "104", "123", "33", 
"41.2", "52", "53", "86", "91", "93.4", "101", "108.1", "116.1", 
"225", "4", "68", "76", "90.5", "92", "25", "44", "49", "58", 
"82", "87", "103", "113", "118", "2", "8", "22", "28", "77", 
"88", "89", "114", "232.1", "11", "42", "59.1", "65", "75", "81", 
"85", "19.4", "218.1", "233", "6", "74", "95"), class = "factor", scores = structure(c(`1` = 2, 
`2` = 12, `3.1` = 4, `4` = 9, `6` = 17, `8` = 12, `11` = 13, 
`12` = 3, `19.4` = 14, `22` = 12, `25` = 11, `28` = 12, `33` = 8, 
`36.2` = 5, `39.4` = 3, `41.2` = 8, `42` = 13, `44` = 11, `49` = 11, 
`52` = 8, `53` = 8, `54.1` = 5, `58` = 11, `59.1` = 13, `65` = 13, 
`68` = 10, `71` = 6, `74` = 18, `75` = 13, `76` = 10, `77` = 12, 
`81` = 13, `82` = 11, `85` = 13, `86` = 8, `87` = 11, `88` = 12, 
`89` = 12, `90.5` = 10, `91` = 8, `92` = 10, `93.4` = 8, `95` = 19, 
`100` = 6, `101` = 8, `103` = 11, `104` = 6, `108.1` = 8, `113` = 11, 
`114` = 12, `116.1` = 8, `118` = 11, `123` = 7, `197` = 1, `218.1` = 15, 
`225` = 8, `232.1` = 12, `233` = 16, `238.1` = 2), .Dim = 59L, .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3.1", "4", "6", "8", "11", "12", "19.4", "22", 
    "25", "28", "33", "36.2", "39.4", "41.2", "42", "44", "49", 
    "52", "53", "54.1", "58", "59.1", "65", "68", "71", "74", 
    "75", "76", "77", "81", "82", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", 
    "90.5", "91", "92", "93.4", "95", "100", "101", "103", "104", 
    "108.1", "113", "114", "116.1", "118", "123", "197", "218.1", 
    "225", "232.1", "233", "238.1"))))), row.names = c(NA, -74L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I have plotted a Heatmap for both cases and controls with the following code:

```
(cases_heatmap <- ggplot(filter(example, group == "case"), aes(id, factor(emm_type)))+geom_tile(aes(fill=value_mean), colour="white")+
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", midpoint = 60,limits=c(0,max(example$value_mean)))+
    scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.6),legend.position = "none")+
    coord_equal())

(cases_heatmap <- ggplot(filter(example, group == "control"), aes(id, factor(emm_type)))+geom_tile(aes(fill=value_mean), colour="white")+
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", mid = "white", high = "red", midpoint = 60,limits=c(0,max(example$value_mean)))+
    scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 0)) +
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.6),legend.position = "none")+
    coord_equal())
```

Which gives me something like this (one for cases and one for controls:

[image]

In order to plot the cluster and pattern along side it I adapt the data a bit to get a column I can plot (using "cluster_text" and "pattern_text" columns), as well as having a number to sort by (num_cluster):

```
example <- example%>%
  mutate(num_cluster = as.numeric(factor(example$cluster))) %>%
  mutate(num_pattern = as.numeric(factor(example$pattern))) %>%
  mutate(cluster_text = "Cluster") %>%
  mutate(pattern_text = "Pattern")
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO1eP.jpg
```

As I want the clusters to be grouped together I reorder the levels:

```
example$emm_type <- reorder(example$emm_type, example$cluster)
```

Then in order to get the annotation bars (of Cluster and Pattern) with colours which I would like to plot along side the Heatmap I plot another geom_tile, of the newly created "cluster_text" and "pattern_text" columns:

```
cluster_annotation <- ggplot(filter(example, group == "case"), aes(cluster_text, factor(emm_type)))+geom_tile(aes(fill=cluster), colour="white")+
  coord_equal()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())


pattern_annotation <- ggplot(filter(example, group == "case"), aes(pattern_text, factor(emm_type)))+geom_tile(aes(fill=pattern), colour="white")+
  coord_equal()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

Which gives me the desired annotation tiles (this one for cluster, I get the same for pattern):

[image]

Now I would like all the tiles next to each other, or even plotted on the same geom_tile, so that the emm_types align with their respective pattern and cluster, but can not for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Here is a picture of my final graphs that I would like aligned next to each other when I used more of my data:

[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/C/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2  cowplot_0.9.3   scales_0.5.0    forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.6     purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.1     tibble_1.4.2   
[11] ggplot2_3.0.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 readxl_1.1.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18     cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.3.0     compiler_3.5.0   plyr_1.8.4       bindr_0.1.1      tools_3.5.0      digest_0.6.15    lubridate_1.7.4 
[10] jsonlite_1.5     nlme_3.1-137     gtable_0.2.0     lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.1  rlang_0.2.1      cli_1.0.0        rstudioapi_0.7   yaml_2.2.0      
[19] haven_1.1.2      withr_2.1.2      xml2_1.2.0       httr_1.3.1       hms_0.4.2        tidyselect_0.2.4 glue_1.3.0       R6_2.2.2         fansi_0.2.3     
[28] reshape2_1.4.3   modelr_0.1.2     magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.2  rvest_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.0 colorspace_1.3-2 labeling_0.3     utf8_1.1.4      
[37] stringi_1.2.4    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.0      crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the "Cluster" column and the "Pattern" column to be plotted on the same `geom_tile()` we need to reshape the data from wide to long first.

```
library(tidyr)
example %>% 
  gather(annotation, value, cluster, pattern) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(annotation, factor(emm_type)))+geom_tile(aes(fill=value), colour="white")+
  coord_equal()+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.6)) -> p_annotation
```

Combine the plots.

```
library(patchwork)
cases_heatmap + controls_heatmap + p_annotation
```

[image]

---

**first try**

There are a few packages* that allow to combine ggplot objects, one of which is [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork).

```
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
cases_heatmap + controls_heatmap + cluster_annotation + pattern_annotation + 
plot_layout(nrow = 1)
```

[image]

*Other packages are [`egg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/index.html), [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html), [`multipanelfigure`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multipanelfigure/index.html), ... .

Comment: Thanks for this, yes I used cowplot to plot the final graphic in the "final" graphic in my question. The issue is that I would like the "Cluster" column and the "Pattern" column to be plotted on the same geom_tile. This is because I would like the cluster and pattern if each emm_type to be very easily discernible across the geom_tile. If there is a work around to be able to plot them right next to each other (preferably with legends all off to one side together) then that would also work.

Comment: @reubenmcg Thanks for the reply. Edited the answer. Let me know if it is still not o.k. for you. Best

Comment: Thanks this works, another issue is that ggplot2 does not allow more than one fill colour. I have got around this in the past using colour and fill with different aesthetics, but that does not work for geom_tile. FOR ANYONE LOOKING FOR A SIMILAR SOLUTION, I would recommend not using ggplot for this instance and going to: https://software.broadinstitute.org/morpheus/.